# Libgdx - Keeping an object at certain distance and direction from other object

Tags: math, vector, algebra

So let's say I have 2 objects. One with the sprite of a circle, other with the sprite of triangle.
My triangle object is set to the position of mouse in every step of the game, while circle is either standing in place or just moving in its own way, whatever.
What I want to do is to have the TRIANGLE move around the circle, but not on it's own, rather on the way your cursor is positioned.

So basically, calculate degree between circle's center and triangle's center. Whenever they are far from each other I just set triangle position to mouse position, BUT when you hover your mouse too close (past some X distance) you can't get any closer (the TRIANGLE is then positioned at maximum that X distance in the direction from circle center to mouse point)

I'll add a picture and hopefully you can get what I mean.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23334107/help2.png

Answer (score 2):

### Steps:

**1.** Calculate the distance between the cursor and the center of the circle. If it is more than the 'limit' then set the triangle's position to the cursor's position and skip to step **4.**

**2.** Obtain the angle formed between the center of the circle and the cursor.

**3.** Calculate the new Cartesian coordinates (x, y) of the triangle based of off the polar coordinates we have now (angle and radius). The radius will be set to the limit of the circle before we calculate x and y, because we want the triangle to be prevented from entering this limit.

**4.** Rotate the image of the triangle to `1.5708-angle` where angle was found in step **2.** (1.5708, or pi/2, in radians is equivalent to 90°)

---

### Details:

**1.** The distance between two points `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` is `sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2))`

**2.** The angle (in radians) can be calculated with

```
double angle = Math.atan2(circleY-cursorY, cursorX-circleX);
```

The seemingly mistaken difference in order of `circleY-cursorY` and `cursorX-circleX` is an artefact of the coordinate system in most programming languages. (The y coordinate increases *downwards* instead of upwards, as it does in mathematics, while the x coordinate increases in concord with math - to the right.)

**3.** To convert polar coordinates to Cartesian coordinates use these conversions:

```
triangle.setX( cos(angle)*limit );
triangle.setY( sin(angle)*limit );
```

where limit is the distance you want the triangle to remain from the circle.

**4.** In order to get your triangle to 'face' the circle (as you illustrated), you have to rotate it using the libgdx Sprite function [setRotation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#setRotation%28float%29).  It will rotate around the point set with [setOrigin](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#setOrigin%28float,%20float%29).

Now, you have to rotate by `1.5708-angle` – this is because of further differences between angles in mathematics and angles in programming! The `atan2` function returns the angle as measured mathematically, with 0° at three o'clock and increasing counterclockwise. The `setRotation` function (as far as I can tell) has 0° at twelve o'clock and increases clockwise.  Also, we have to convert from radians to degrees. In short, this should work, but I haven't tested it:

```
triangle.setRotation(Math.toDegrees(1.4708-angle));
```

---

Hope this helps!